# Getting data without a key. Only with information on child nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

I'm having a really hard time understanding how Nosql works so I hope someone can help me understand it a bit better.

I'm trying to make a simple chat application (One to one chat support and chat groups) and want to dislay a list of all the conversations that the current user is in. This is my table for it.

[image]

I tried getting the data in several ways. But what I currently have is this (Which should work according to the internet, but doesn't).

```
_membersRef.equalTo(1508, key: '1508').once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
            print(snap.value);
        });
```

I also tried

```
_membersRef.startAt(1508).endAt(1508).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
            print(snap.value);
        });
```

What I want my code to do is return all records that have my account_id in them (1508 in this case). So it should return the record "one".

So if I change the uid in the code to 1509 it should return "One" and "two". How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the key `one` try this:

```
_membersRef.orderByChild('1508').equalTo(true).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) { 
print(snap.value); 
});
```

the snapshot is at child `members` then you order it according to child `1508` which is `equalTo(true)`.

Comment: This still returns all the records but with the correct records on top. But the app should not receive members that are not his. That would be a huge privacy problem.

I'm getting this back:
{one: {1509: true, 1508: true}, two: {1509: true}}

"two" should not be in the received data

Comment: try `child("members").orderByChild("1508").equalTo(true)`

Comment: Omg I think it works!!!! If you can change your answer code to `_membersRef.orderByChild('1508').equalTo(true).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
            print(snap.value);
        });` Then I can vote yours as the answer as this is a flutter question and not javascript. But thank you so much!

Comment: While this query works, it requires that you have a index defined on `1508`, `1509`, etc. If those child nodes are not pre-defined, that is likely not feasible and you should create an inverted data structure as Günter's answer shows. Also have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value